# How to resolve a "Null manifest from input stream associated with" warning

Tags: java

I'm trying to stop the warning:

```
JarClassLoader: Warning: Null manifest from input stream associated with: <path to lib / jar file>
```

which gets displayed every time I run my java application. I realise that it doesn't stop it working, but I assume a warning is there for a reason and I'd like to understand why and how.

For reference, the jar file is being created using one-jar.
I've looked at this [stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662659/one-jar-remove-verbose-warning-information-on-application-load) but this seems to be more about suppressing messages rather than resolving them.

It also has been asked [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3139182&group_id=111153&atid=658458) but again I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: does your Jar file have a manifest? Unzip it and take a look in the "META-INF" folder.

Comment: my compiled jar file has a MANIFEST.MF file in it. The file it is complaining about is one of the included .jar files from the lib folder, and when I open that and check it there is a MANIFEST.MF file for that as well

Comment: use a (proper) replacement for one-jar (spring-boot, maven...), or wait until they fix it. ;)

Comment: Just because you have a MANIFEST.MF in your META-INF directory, it does not mean it was referenced in jar creation. My guess is that you would have to specify explicitly the location of your manifest file to the OneJar tool (which I am not familiar with btw), which is pretty dumb on OneJar's part if it is the case.