# How to turn off warnings on application load from one-jar executable?

Tags: sbt, onejar, sbt-onejar

I am using sbt with the one-jar plugin, but when I run the one-jar executable that has been created I get a continuous stream of messages that look like the following:

```
JarClassLoader: Warning: net/liftweb/json/Formats$$anon$4.class in lib/lift-json_2.9.2-2.5-M3.jar is hidden by lib/lift-json_2.9.1-2.4.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: net/liftweb/json/JsonParser$BoolVal$.class in lib/lift-json_2.9.2-2.5-M3.jar is hidden by lib/lift-json_2.9.1-2.4.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: net/liftweb/json/TypeInfo.class in lib/lift-json_2.9.2-2.5-M3.jar is hidden by lib/lift-json_2.9.1-2.4.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: net/liftweb/json/Meta$$anonfun$mappingOf$1.class in lib/lift-json_2.9.2-2.5-M3.jar is hidden by lib/lift-json_2.9.1-2.4.jar (with different bytecode)
```

I tried passing parameters to the jvm as suggested in a couple of the responses to [one-jar remove verbose warning information on application load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662659/one-jar-remove-verbose-warning-information-on-application-load), but I continue to get the annoying warnings.

How does one turn-off these warnings when using sbt-onejar?

I am using the most recent version of [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar).

Comment: Would you mind sharing the build configuration so one could reproduce your error and work it out? I'd rather not have to spend time on doing it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr There's no *easy* way to turn the messages off since they come from `System.err`.

I know little about the plugin so I unzipped the `JarClassLoader` class as follows:

```
jar -xf src/main/resources/one-jar-boot-0.98.jar src/com/simontuffs/onejar/JarClassLoader.java
```

In the class, at line 998 there's the call to `WARNING` method:

```
if (!Arrays.equals(existing.bytes, bytes) && !name.startsWith("META-INF")) {
    // TODO: this really needs to be a warning, but there needs to be a way
    // to shut it down.  INFO it for now.  Ideally we need to provide a 
    // logging layer (like commons-logging) to allow logging to be delegated.
    if (name.endsWith(".class")) {
        // This is probably trouble.
        WARNING(existing.name + " in " + jar + " is hidden by " + existing.codebase + " (with different bytecode)");
    } else {
        INFO(existing.name + " in " + jar + " is hidden by " + existing.codebase + " (with different bytes)");
    }
} else {
    VERBOSE(existing.name + " in " + jar + " is hidden by " + existing.codebase + " (with same bytecode)");
}
```

The method `WARNING` is implemented as follows:

```
protected void WARNING(String message) {
    System.err.println(PREFIX() + "Warning: " + NAME() + message); 
}
```

It's led me to claim that turning it off is impossible (unless you can shut down the entire `System.err` that I don't know being possible).